# "Failed to download package file check your internet connection" while installing packages on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 11.10, software-center

I have just installed Ubuntu 11.10. Now when I try to install packages from the Software Center, I get the message:

> Failed to download package file check your internet connection

I don't understand this because my internet is on every time.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This release of Ubuntu is no longer supported and is now [End Of Life (EOL)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0):

When it tells you this, click on the options or open System Settings and Click on Software and Updates. Then Select the Other Software tab. Finally un-tick the entries starting with

```
http://ppa
```

This should cure the problem.

I believe that the failure is caused by software files not being where the link is pointing to. Try Updating again, then you can go back in to the settings and re-enable each one in turn. Some may work, whilst others may cause the failure again.